# I'm trying to push lightning web component to the Heroku

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, heroku

I'm trying to push lightning web component to heroku platform. I'm getting this error.

I have used heroku commands -- heroku logs --tail

019-11-01T05:12:16.37014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2019-11-01T05:12:24.922757+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start

2019-11-01T05:12:27.40878+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2019-11-01T05:12:27.369911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-01T05:12:27.317819+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start

2019-11-01T05:12:27.326463+00:00 app[web.1]:

2019-11-01T05:12:27.326928+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2019-11-01T05:12:27.327102+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-11-01T05_12_27_318Z-debug.log
2019-11-01T05:12:36.474076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=macabre-fangs-30358.herokuapp.com request_id=399a91da-8fe6-4b4c-b4b8-a8cdb2dc23c4 fwd="106.51.66.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2019-11-01T05:12:37.251927+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=macabre-fangs-30358.herokuapp.com request_id=e675871a-8687-47a9-8a62-2f18d05c87f2 fwd="106.51.66.44" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I have also tried **repush**(git push heroku master) the code to the heroku and tried **refresh** or **restart**(heroku restart) the error code. but it's not solving this issue.

I have one **ProcFile** -- **web: npm run serve**

And i have this file also

**EXPRESS-Dev.js**

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const customServer = require(path.resolve('./src/server/'));

const app = express();

customServer(app);

app.listen(3002, () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('Yay, local server started');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think we need to change the **procfile** slightly
an i have installed yarn. that could be the case also.

so change the **procfile file**

from
**web: npm run serve**

to

**web: npm start**

and add one line in **package.json**

under:

```
Script{
"serve": "lwc-services serve",

//for above line,  when you build the app on heroku it was looking at this script. so i just kept that as it is and added below line.

//also read this doc also for refernce [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type][1]

//add this line to package.json

"start": "lwc-services serve"

{
```